# Find distant parent in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, find, parent

I'm a little stuck on how to track down an element that's up the tree as a parent element.

```
$('.btn-action').hover(
  function(){
    $(this).find('.product-card').addClass('animated bounce');
  },
  function(){
    $(this).find('.product-card').removeClass('animated bounce')
  }
);
```

The `.product-card` class is not the direct parent but further up the tree. I need animate it based on the hover method on the `.btn-action` class. Can this be achieved with `.parent()` or `.find()` ?

Comment: try `.parentS('.product-card')`

Comment: can you post the html?

Comment: clearly going the wrong direction.  Read the [api docs for find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To go up the tree you can use .closest().

```
$(this).closest('.product-card').addClass('animated bounce');
```

To go further in the tree use .find(). 
To stay on the same level, you can use .siblings()

Although I am not sure about the space in your classname. Try using a dash if multiple classes wasn't intended.

Answer (score 0):

I think , you may use `.closest( selector )` method for get the nearest parent of the element.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using .parents()? @see https://api.jquery.com/parents/

To get the .product-card ancestors try:

```
$('.product-card').parents()
```